# How to disable unwanted WebFilter (Embedded inside jar) in Servlet?

Tags: java, servlet-filters, servlet-3.0

In my Servlet application, I'm using a Jar which contains an `@WebFilter` class in it. I should not remove the Jar dependency or the `@WebFilter` class inside it. I tried to set some bogus filter url pattern for the unwanted filter, but it doesn't work as that `@WebFilter` is mapped to `/*`.

```
 package com.somepackage;

 @WebFilter("/*")
 public class CustomFilter implements Filter {
```

This is how I set the bogus url in web.xml

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>CustomFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.somepackage.CustomFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CustomFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/thispathnotexist/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

It doesn;t have any effect as all the requests are still passed through CustomFilter. Is there any way that I can disable this particular filter in my appliction?

Comment: you can try the following answers : http://stackoverflow.com/a/3738257/957654 , http://stackoverflow.com/a/3125315/957654

Comment: @AmroAlFares, That worked perfectly..

Comment: thanks to @BalusC :)

Answer (score 0):

web.xml overrides the annotation. You can declare it in web.xml and with some dummy path

I believe you are looking for [Disable @WebFilter (embedded in dependency jar)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18704226/disable-webfilter-embedded-in-dependency-jar)

Comment: @M Sach, I've already tried that as stated in my post, still the requests are passed through custom filter

Comment: it should work. But still In that case you can try  have filter with same name  which will do nothing and put it in `web-inf/classes`

Comment: It would only work if the filter name is the same. However, the @WebFilter doesn't have a filter name defined. So basically you're just adding another one.

Comment: @BalusC in this case under web.xml filtername does not matter. what will matter is filter class name